# Error compiling and installing mcrypt from source

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, compile, make

I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on my current issue.

**Scenario:** Installing libmcrypt, mhash and mcrypt from source in order to compile PHP5.4 with the mcrypt extension enabled.

**OS:** RHEL-6 (on openshift)

**Steps:**
Compiled and installed libmcrypt and mhash with no issues. Moved on to install mcrypt and initially, I had an issue with it not finding the mhash lib.  I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383492/cant-compile-mcrypt-configure-failed-mhash-keygen-in-lmhash-no)!

After exporting the env vars, I was able to get pass that error but now mcrypt fails to compile because of the following error:

```
configure: WARNING: mcrypt.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
```

I pulled the config.log and I am seeing this error:

```
configure:6289: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:6329: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:6335: $? = 0
configure:6366: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:13:28: error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
configure:6372: $? = 1
```

I've been searching across the Internet and no luck so far. Any ideas on what I need to do in order to successfully compile/install mcrypt?

Do I need to export another env var to help my preprocessor find the right libs or?

Here are the commands I passed:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/libmcrypt/lib:/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/mhash/lib

export LDFLAGS="-L/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/mhash/lib"

export CFLAGS="-I/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/mhash/include"

#mcrypt
 ./configure --prefix=/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/mcrypt --with-libmcrypt-prefix=/var/lib/openshift/515b7bbd4382eca7d500002a/diy-0.1/runtime/srv/libmcrypt
```